# Create custom 'non differentiable' activation function in keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, activation-function

Is it possible to create a custom activation function of the form:

```
def newactivation(x):
    if x <= -1:
        return -1
    elif x > -1 and x <= 1
        return x
    else :
        return 1
```

So basically it would be a linearized version of tanh(x).

Is it a problem during optimization, that the function has two non differentiable positions at -1 and 1?

How could I implement this?

Comment: Should not be a problem I think. Even the `ReLu` is not differentiable at 0. Do check the source code implementation to see how they handle that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to implement with the clip function:

```
import keras.backend as K

def activation(x):
    return K.clip(x, -1.0, 1.0)
```

Since the gradient never explodes, it should not be an issue, this function has a shape similar to the ReLU.

Comment: It's not working. K.min() and K.max() input a tensor and return the min/max value along an axis, which in your case is specified as 1 and -1. [ K.min(tensor,axis)]

Comment: @KlemensKasseroller Yes true, fixed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank You!